# ES6 Modules in Chrome & Node... `export function` or `module.exports = function`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, es6-modules

I have a module like this:

```
module.exports = class Edge {
    constructor(vertex1, vertex2) {
        this.vertex1 = vertex1;
        this.vertex2 = vertex2;
    }
}
```

I want to import it into some NodeJS files and some front-end files in Chrome. I know Chrome now supports ES6 modules, but importing is giving me trouble:

> ReferenceError: module is not defined

I think I'm supposed to use `export class { ... }`, but that's NOT supported in NodeJS right? How can I make this module work with both Chrome and NodeJS?

Answer (score 4):

[ES6 modules are currently supported under a flag](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html), so it is possible to have your file work natively in both environments. A few important things to note:

- In Node, the file has to have an .mjs extension, so Node knows beforehand to load it as an ES module instead of a CommonJS module
- Browsers don't automatically search for .js or .mjs extensions. You have to add them yourself when importing, e.g. `import { Edge } from './edge.mjs'`

However, the technology is still new and experimental, and there's not a lot of documentation or material on the subject. That, and relying on native technology isn't a good idea if you want to support older node environments and browsers.

If you want to support older environments, you can use a tool like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to "bundle" up your files into one big JS file that any environment can run.

Lastly, [look more into ES modules and gain a good understanding of how the syntax works in detail (defaults especially)](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html), so you'll run into less problems later.

Comment: It should be "**ES6 modules** are currently supported under a flag". Node has always supported "NodeJS modules".

Answer (score 0):

Use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and compile your code

Comment: Is the only way to use a compiler?

Comment: Ok. What would Babel do (I never used it)? Would it make a version for Node and a version for Chrome? 2 files?

Comment: Babel would translate the ES6 import/export statements into CommonJS to allow them to run in Node. However you wouldn't run babel for chrome, since chrome supports the ES6 syntax natively.

Comment: Also the NPM developers have come up with a new proposal for the module system in node so it will prob take some time before it gets accepted. Babel is the only way to go atm.